# Making string to object?

Tags: php, string, function

I'm having a problem when converting a string to an object. Here is the function:

```
public function slikepoid($dire,$id)
{
    $this->dire=$dire;
    $this->id=$id;
    $slike = $this->skupljanjeslika($this->dire);
    $slikeid = array_filter($slike, function($el) { 
        return substr( $el, 0, 2) == '$this->id-'; // Here is the problem !
    });
    return $slikeid;
}
```

I got this error:

**Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context on line 8**

I tried:

```
 return substr( $el, 0, 2) == ''.(string)$this->id;'-';
```

But no luck :(

Comment: In PHP 5.3, you can't use `$this` inside anonymous functions (closures).  I think you can do that in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Yes but how to convert constructor in string?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use a [closure](http://php.net/closure) to accomplish this:

```
$slikeid = array_filter($slike, function($el) use( $id) { 
    return substr( $el, 0, 2) == $id; 
});
```

Now, `$id` should be inside the scope of the anonymous function, so you should be able to compare the element value against it.

Comment: public function slikepoid($dire,$id) - its define closure??